# Wrong appearance of top navigation bar when down- / upsizing page

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I have a small display error with a navigation bar (HTML/CSS code in sharepoint websitesite (implemented with modern script editor plugin). When you reduce or enlarge the page, the navigation bar is split into 2 lines.

**Behaviour / appearance of top navigation bar at 100% page size:**

[image]

**Behaviour / appearance of top navigation bar at approx. 80% page size:**

[image]

The underlying problem is not quite clear to me, since the icon is also scaled and should not actually be the problem.

I could fix this by making the navigation bar wider, but then the cell of the last item "KPIs and maturity scoring" would not change color completely on :hover. So I would like to exclude this solution.

**Is there anything I can do to suppress this behavior?**

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1085px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: center;
  margin-left: -32px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav div a {
  float: left;
  color: lightgrey;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
}

.topnav div a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: lightgrey;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
    

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Index</a>
 
     <a href="">Ziele</a>
     <a href="">Organisation & Rollen</a>
     <a href="">Standards</a>     
     <a href="">Software</a>
     <a href="">Kommunikation</a>
     <a href="">Innovation</a>
     <a href="">Prozesse</a>
  
     <div>
        <a>Ausbildung</a>
     </div>

     <a href="">Projekte</a>
     <a href="">KPIs und Reifegrad</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code has not been changed, i only removed the href's as they point to local sharepoint paths.

Comment: use **%** instead of **px** or **@media screen** for different screen size